# MS Detours 2.1 - Popping out of stack

Tags: c++, winapi, code-injection, detours

I wont to detour PlaySoundW function inside Minesweeper.
Game is crashing as soon as it calls PlaySoundW function.
If I uncomment Beep inside my code, game beeps and than crashes.

Now code is calling original function from hooked function so it should't do anything. But it is crashing anyway.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

After debugging app in Olly I found that when detour is active not all rubbish is popped out of stack.
How to fix it?

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <detours.h>

namespace Hooks
{
    BOOL(__stdcall *OrgPlaySoundW)(LPCTSTR pszSound, HMODULE hmod, DWORD fdwSound) = &PlaySoundW;

    BOOL HookPlaySoundW(LPCTSTR pszSound, HMODULE hmod, DWORD fdwSound)
    {
        //Beep(1000, 250);
        //return TRUE;
        return OrgPlaySoundW(pszSound, hmod, fdwSound);
    }

    void DetourPlaySoundW(BOOL disable)
    {
        if(!disable)
        {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)OrgPlaySoundW, &HookPlaySoundW);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
        } else 
        {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)OrgPlaySoundW, &HookPlaySoundW);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
        }
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Hooks::DetourPlaySoundW(FALSE);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Hooks::DetourPlaySoundW(TRUE);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Does Detours really require all that horrid casting (of function pointers nonetheless)?

Comment: @Ben yes, and horrid is a point of view, like Lisp's parentheses.

Comment: @Seth: *undefined behavior* is not a point of view.  Casting between function pointers and `void*` is undefined behavior.  That code isn't valid C++.  They should at least have used `FARPROC` (like `GetProcAddress` returns) which is guaranteed to be the right size for a function pointer.

Comment: @Ben when people say _undefined behaviour_ do they mean the standard doesn't define what should happen so the compiler writers get to decide what happens? In any case, it works.

Comment: @Seth: The standard has another name for that: *implementation-defined behavior*.  And actually, that's the correct term here, not *undefined behavior*.  "Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning
of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in
both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-
qualification, shall yield the original pointer value."

Comment: @Ben thanks for the clarification. I think MSVC++ would fall under the "implementation supporting conversions in both directions", which is what I assume people are using when they are using Microsoft Detours, unless they say otherwise.

Comment: Whereas conversions between function pointers are defined by the standard: "A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a diﬀerent type." ... "Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to
T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the
result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the calling convention of `HookPlaySoundW` to `__stdcall` (because the CC of `PlaySoundW` is also `__stdcall` (from `Windows.h`): `WINMMAPI BOOL WINAPI PlaySoundW( __in_opt LPCWSTR pszSound, __in_opt HMODULE hmod, __in DWORD fdwSound);`).

I have worked with detours before and after a casual glance everything looks correct except what I mentioned above. If this doesn't resolve your problem I'd be glad to do some further investigation.

The default setting for Visual C++ is `__cdecl` in which the call**er** cleans up the stack, but in `__stdcall` the call**ee** cleans up the stack. This is probably (*i.e.* might possibly be) the reason for all the "rubbish being popped off the stack".